# How do you access the files of a repo that was cloned during a GCP image build once you've started a VM with the resulting image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm attempting to create a GCP image in the Container Registry which contains a repository I want to use in a VM.

First off I have a Dockerfile which clones a repo from github eg:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y git

RUN mkdir -p /opt/repo-location

WORKDIR /opt/repo-location/
RUN git clone git@github.com:random/repo.git
```

I use a cloudbuild.yml file for gcloud to use:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build',
         '-t',
         'gcr.io/project-id/image-name',
         '.']
images: [
    'gcr.io/project-id/image-name',
]
```

I can then run that successfully which creates the image in the registry and I am then able to create a VM instance using that image. However, when I ssh into the instance and go to `/opt/` the `repo-location` folder isn't there.

I've done a bunch of reading and I can see how files created during the build aren't accessible once the build is complete but I cant work out how to get it so they'll be present on the VM once its created.

I'd like the build to be able to do a bunch of initial configuration steps on the cloned repo so I can then ssh in and manually start the process from the git repo.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: When you say "create a VM" and "ssh", do you mean you're creating a virtual machine, installing Docker in it, and `docker run` the image you created?  Or are you using `docker run` and `docker exec` to inspect the image's contents?

Comment: I'm using gcloud build and Docker to create a Google cloud image and am then selecting that as a base when creating an instance in GCP